# Cache response but always check for newer version

Tags: asp.net-core, http, caching, browser-cache

I have a http API that returns PDF file that is then shown in frame.
The file is occasionally updated on the server.

How to tell the browser to always check whether there is a newer version on the server, but avoid downloading the cached version again?

So when requesting the file, the browser should include some timestamp or version number of currently cached file in some header.
The server would respond with a newer version or with HTTP code 304 - Not Modified

Comment: Well, it's up to me how I embed the PDF. Now it's an frame, but can be anything else.

Comment: The point is, I always need to display up to date version, but avoid downloading the same file over and over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response should include the following headers:

- `Cache-Control: no-cache`
- `ETag: ...`

The `Cache-Control` tells the browser to keep the file in the cache but to check with the server each time to make sure the cached response is current.

The `ETag` is used to identify the current version of the file. You can provide your own value (it could be a version number, say) or you can let your web framework handle it automatically (generally by hashing the contents of the response). I don't use ASP.NET but I assume there's a standard way of enabling this functionality.

Comment: The server should return 304 or the browser just won't download the file if etag header is not updated

Comment: @Liero: Right, the server compares the ETag given in the `If-None-Match` request header to the current ETag and then either sends the full response or a 304. You can do that comparison yourself, but most web frameworks will do that for you.

Comment: I will just add, that Chromium browsers does not send `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` with request to localhost or if there is a certificate errors. Additionally Kestrel webserver deletes the headers before it gets to asp. For local testing use http://127.0.0.1.